# WCF: need a way to gracefully terminate request

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that performs a lengthy operation. I have the following issue:

1) A client makes a call to my function

2) .net framework starts a worker thread that executes the request asynchronously

3) The service is shut down, BEFORE the above request is complete

4) Client receives 404 response (Not registered)

5) The thread continues to run (!) until the application is complete and then it is just removed without warning (Abort signal or something)

I need a way to gracefully terminate the worker thread and send a 503 response to the client.

Comment: Is there a `CommunicationException` thrown?

Comment: No Exception is thrown in the worker thread, not even ThreadAbortException

Comment: Which of these is actually on the server? It isn't clear.

Comment: I am describing WCF server side.

Comment: My WCF web service immediately sends an error to the client when the service is shut down - but my ws is self-hosted. If you had your web service fronted by IIS, you might be able to configure a custom error for the clients when the service dies. That's the only thing I can think of .

Comment: Mine is self-hosted too. The client however cannot recognize between the situation when service dies and not registered - in both cases it gets http 404 error. That's the problem.

Comment: If i understand, you make a call, and shut down the service before the service return answer to client (async), is this normal behavior of service ?

Comment: No, this is not normal behavior, but the client needs a way to determine if the service was shutdown prematurely or not registered.